# How to get list of all Azure VMs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I'm attempting to get a list of all my Azure VMs in Powershell.

```
Get-AzureVM
```

Unfortunately this only returns the VMs listed under **Virtual machines (classic)**.

[image]

How can I get a list of the new Virtual machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Azure Resource Manager mode to access the new VMs:

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
```

You can read more about it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/).

Answer (score 6):

Based on David's answer, I wrote the following script that combines the two lists of VMs:

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureServiceManagement
#ResourceGroupName will be blank for these
$classicVms = Get-AzureVM | select Name, ServiceName, ResourceGroupName

Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager    
#ServiceName will be blank for these
$armVms = Get-AzureVM | select Name, ServiceName, ResourceGroupName 

$allVms = $classicVms + $armVms
$allVms
```

When you run this, you'll get a warning that Switch-AzureMode is deprecated.

```
WARNING: The Switch-AzureMode cmdlet is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

The deprecation is part of a breaking change. You can read the details here: [Deprecation of Switch-AzureMode](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell).

Comment: Nice. +1. Also, thanks for pointing out the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Switch-AzureMode has now been deprecated (https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell).   Cmdlet Rename All cmdlets under Azure Resource Management modules will be renamed to fit the following format: [Verb]-AzureRm[Noun]

Example: New-AzureVm becomes New-AzureRmVm

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/), we can use the `az vm list` command to get a list of all VMs in the current subscription. Adding on this, we just loop over all our subscriptions and add the results to a single list

```
$results=New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList;

$subs = az account list | ConvertFrom-Json;
$subIndex = 0;
foreach ($sub in $subs)
{
    $subIndex++;
    Write-Progress "Gathering VMs" -Status $sub.name -PercentComplete ($subIndex / $subs.Count * 100)
    $vms = az vm list --subscription $sub.id | ConvertFrom-Json
    $results.Add(@{
        subscription = $sub
        vms = $vms
    }) > $null;
    $results | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 > vms.json;
}
```

This, however, [does not include the power on/off state of the vms](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/154)

We can get all the VM info + the power state using the `az graph query` command. This has the benefit of being even faster. A little work is needed to process the paginated results, but it's still fairly easy.

```
$query = "
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend PowerState = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code)
| extend vmSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize)
";

$params = @(
    "--graph-query", $query -replace "`n", ""
    "--output", "json"
);

$total=New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList;
$count=0;
while ($true)
{
    $results = az graph query @params | ConvertFrom-Json;
    foreach ($d in $results.data)
    {
        $total.Add($d);
    }
    $count += $results.count;
    $params = @(
        "--graph-query", $query -replace "`n", ""
        "--output", "json"
        "--skip-token", $results.skip_token
        "--skip", $count
    );
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($results.skip_token)) {break;}
}

$total | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 > vms_fast.json;
```

[Note that we use array splatting instead of object splatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854092/how-to-use-powershell-splatting-for-azure-cli)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Az Module installed, try:

```
Get-AzVM
```

[Examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-8.2.0)